# Where is DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver located in Umbraco Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, umbraco

For custom controller hijacking as mentioned umbraco documentation here [Custom controllers (Hijacking Umbraco Routes)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers)

I am not unable to find the namespace and assembly for the class mentioned as `DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver` for the code snippet below,

```
public class MyApplication : UmbracoApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver.Current.SetDefaultControllerType(typeof(MyCustomUmbracoController));
        base.OnApplicationStarting(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace is `Umbraco.Web.Mvc` but only available from v6.1 onwards I think.

All the code is open source and available at https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS

Comment: ok I had 6.0.5 version that is the reason I didn't find it. Thanks. Can you tell me how I can update the version of umbraco now (as I am still in development phase) ?

Comment: Go to http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases for the releases, each one has upgrade instructions.

Comment: Do you think nuget command will be appropriate when I have vs solution of umbraco site `Update-Package UmbracoCms` ?

Comment: If you are already using nuget, then yes that should be fine and is the preferred option.

Comment: I faced some issues in upgrading but finally managed with some manual efforts and also copying the folder from the new version's zip files as mentioned in this link http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/general under heading `Copying files` Thanks again.